# Psql - ERROR: column "avclass" does not exist - selecting counts and percentages for columns that are grouped

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

This is the query i'm trying to do. I'm no expert at psql.

```
SELECT avclassfamily, count(*) as countis, totalcount, percentage  
FROM malwarehashesandstrings 
where lol=True 
group by avclassfamily 
ORDER BY countis DESC;
```

avclassfamily = that string

count(*) = total count where lol=true

totalcount = count where lol=true or lol=false for that particular avclassfamily

percentage = count as a percentage of totalcount

This was the first command i used

```
SELECT avclassfamily, count(*) as countis 
FROM malwarehashesandstrings 
where lol=True 
group by avclassfamily 
ORDER BY countis DESC;
```

This is the output of the above command:

```
 avclassfamily      | countis 
------------------------+---------
 autoit                 |     677
 cosmu                  |     226
 SINGLETON              |     223
 plingky                |     195
 fakepav                |     186
```

Here is my attempt to get closer to what I am looking for:

```
SELECT avclassfamily as avclass, count(*) as countis, 
       (select count(*) 
        FROM malwarehashesandstrings 
        where avclassfamily=avclass) as percent 
from malwarehashesandstrings 
where lol=True 
group by avclassfamily 
ORDER BY countis DESC;
```

The correct sql is:

```
select avclassfamily as avclass, 
       count(*) as countis,
       sum(case when avclassfamily = avclassfamily and lol=True then 1 else 0 end) as lolnumber , 
       case 
         sum(case when avclassfamily = avclassfamily and lol=True then 1 else 0 end) when 0 
           then NULL 
         else (sum(case when avclassfamily = avclassfamily and lol=True then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) ) 
       end as percentage
from malwarehashesandstrings 
group by avclassfamily 
order by percentage desc NULLS LAST;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a `subquery` on your column, what you need is `sum` and `select case`

```
select avclassfamily as avclass
, count(*) as countis,
sum(case when avclassfamily = avclassfamily and lol=True then 1 else 0 end) as lolnumber
, 
case sum(case when avclassfamily = avclassfamily and lol=True then 1 else 0 end) when 0 then NULL else (sum(case when avclassfamily = avclassfamily and lol=True then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) ) end as percentage
```

from malwarehashesandstrings 
group by avclassfamily 
order by percentage desc NULLS LAST;

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid i still get the error "column avclass does not exist", with that query.

Comment: The same output

Comment: Worked it out, with your help, thank you very much. Have submitted an edit, please approve then i'll put as right answer.